# Java thread interruption won't work for me (in groovy)

Tags: multithreading, groovy, interrupted-exception

Feeling stupid somehow as I'm now trying to get a simple interrupt for a thread working in groovy for some hours already.

Somehow following code won't set the 'interrupted' flag in the thread 'name'. Causing the loop to run 'til its end.

Found tons of other questions where usually the check for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` was missing. But this is not the case here:

```
def t = Thread.start('name') {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(); ++i) {
            println "$i"
            sleep 1000
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        println "Catched exception"
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
println "Interrupting thread in 1..."
sleep 1000
println "Interrupting thread..."
t.interrupt()
sleep 2000
```

I get following output

```
Interrupting thread in 1...
0
Interrupting thread...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Wonder what I miss here / am doing wrong?
Tried also using `ExecutorService` and calling `cancel(true)` on the returned Future. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** Do not use `Thread` interruption as abort criterion, but use some custom flag instead.

---

You are not using `Thread.sleep()` which would throw `InterruptedException`, but GDKs `Object.sleep()` which handles and ignores interruptions: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#sleep(long)

Either use `Thread.sleep()` instead like: (interrupting in the catch block is useless in your case)

```
def t = Thread.start('name') {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !Thread.interrupted(); ++i) {
            println i
            Thread.sleep 1000
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        println "Catched exception"
    }
}
println "Interrupting thread in 1..."
sleep 1000
println "Interrupting thread..."
t.interrupt()
```

Or use the variant of `Object.sleep()` with a `Closure` and abort your loop in there, e. g. by throwing `InterruptedException` like:

```
def t
t = Thread.start('name') {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !Thread.interrupted(); ++i) {
            println i
            sleep(1000) {
                throw new InterruptedException()
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        println "Catched exception"
    }
}
println "Interrupting thread in 1..."
sleep 1000
println "Interrupting thread..."
t.interrupt()
```

---

Having solved your confusion, now let me advice not to do what you are trying to do. Interrupting is any no way a good method for usage as abort condition. A sleep or blocking IO can always be interrupted due to various reasons. The much better approach is to make your run-loop check some `boolean` flag that you toggle to abort the work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Should have noted that in the first place I got it working using a custom flag; however after searching the net I found lot of posts telling that one should rather use the built-in interrupt functionality for stop execution of a thread. But probably that just for java. Just for clarification: I won't run into trouble with regards to synchronization of that flag which is written in one thread and read in another one?

Comment: Java or Groovy is no difference here. My advice actually was for Java but is true the same for Groovy as it is built upon Java. Actually it is better to use executors and tasks instead of threads whereever possible, because they are thoroughly written and tested. But yes, you have to synchronize access to that flag variable of course to be able to safely modify and access it from multiple threads.

Answer (score 4):

If you interrupt the thread while `sleep`ing, the sleeping interrupted thread [catches](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#sleep(long)) the `InterruptedException` thrown by `Thread.sleep` and the interrupted status is cleared. So your `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` always returns `false`.

You can make your code work if you replace `sleep 1000` with `Thread.sleep(1000)`.